# How do I avoid a JPanel from resizing automatically?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout

I have a very simple login screen. When it fails to authenticate the user it adds an error message (on a different JPanel). When such error message appear the JPanel containing the login form changes size.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LoginScreen {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JLabel errorLabel;

    public LoginScreen() {
        frame = new JFrame("Login");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2, 0, 0));
        JPanel errorPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        formPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        errorPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        usernameField = new JTextField(30);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(30);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String username = usernameField.getText();
                char[] passwordChars = passwordField.getPassword();
                String password = new String(passwordChars);

                // Perform authentication here
                if (authenticate(username, password)) {
                    System.out.println("all good");
                } else {
                    showError("Invalid username or password");
                }
            }
        });

        errorLabel = new JLabel();
        errorLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);

        formPanel.add(usernameLabel);
        formPanel.add(usernameField);
        formPanel.add(passwordLabel);
        formPanel.add(passwordField);
        formPanel.add(new JLabel());
        formPanel.add(loginButton);

        errorPanel.add(errorLabel);

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        mainPanel.add(formPanel, constraints);

        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        mainPanel.add(errorPanel, constraints);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    }

    private boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        // Implement your authentication logic here
        // You can make a request to the backend or check against a local database
        // Return true if the authentication is successful, false otherwise
        return username.equals("admin") && password.equals("password");
    }

    private void showError(String errorMessage) {
        errorLabel.setText(errorMessage);
    }

    public void show() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoginScreen loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
        loginScreen.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this change: `errorLabel = new JLabel(" ");`

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks! I have another small issue. When i put it full screen the formatting changes. Any tips on that?

Comment: *When i put it full screen the formatting changes* Use layout managers effectively. Some layout managers provide dynamic resizing, other retain size. Determine which layout manger(s) are effective for you. GridLayout will resize automatically to take up all the available space. You could use a "wrapper" panel. A panel will a FlowLayout respects the size of the components added. So you could add the form panel to a "wrapper panel and then add the wrapper panel to the main panel.